# kendoAutoComplete doesn't load all elements at the initial stage

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-autocomplete

I have a auto search box.It initially load elements after type some thing.Is there a way to load all elements without typing anything in the text box. 
My code is like this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderItemModels.ProductName, new {@class = "form-control", @id = "txtProductName", @onblur = "IsValidProductName()", @placeholder = @Resources.ProductName })

$("#txtProductName").kendoAutoComplete({
            minLength: 1,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "../PurchaseOrder/Search",
                    parameterMap: function (data) {
                        return { wildcard: $("#searchSomething").val() };
                    }
                }
            },
            select: onSelectName,
            filter: "contains",
        });
```

Comment: Try setting the minLength to 0.

Comment: minLength=0 not working. I have tried before

Comment: Do you really need an autocomplete? A combobox will let you load all the data initially with the autoBind parameter, you can also filter the entries by freetext just like an autocomplete.

Comment: I just want to load all the data in the initial stage. _Combobox is not suitable_  for that purpose.

Comment: Why is ComboBox not suitable? It is the best choice for this situation. The only difference between ComboBox and AutoComplete is that one loads everything in the beginning which is ComboBox